# Android Handler Not Calling Method

Tags: android, methods, timer, bluetooth, handler

I am trying to start a timer on both phones that are connected through bluetooth. I have the timer setup in a method called startSensing().

The timer is activated via an onclick event. I want to have the other phone's startSensing method called as well so they will act in parallel.

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case START_TIMER:
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "start timer");
                startSensing();
                break;
            }
        }
     }


public void startSensing() {
    v.vibrate(500);
    senseCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(senseTime*1000, dt){
    ...
```

The log message shows up the but only the phone where the button was physically pressed starts.

Comment: how do you send the message to handler?

Comment: Through a separate class/thread. I didn't include it since my log message showed up.

Comment: you mean log messages on both phones showed up? why not add a log message to `startSensing` method?

Comment: Ah, I feel foolish now. No it only showed up on the sending side. Sorry for the mistake, this is my first foray into Bluetooth so my troubleshooting is a bit off. I am using the handler from the [Android Bluetooth chat] (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) and I added 

' public void startTimer() {
  mHandler.obtainMessage(PhysicsGizmoActivity.START_TIMER).sendToTarget(); }'

to the bottom of the BluetoothChatService code outside the ConnectedThread class.

Comment: so please post codes that you invoke `startTimer()` method

Comment: I figured it out, I was trying to send information across the phones outside the I/O stream. I send the string "start timer" and look for it in the handler. Works perfectly! Thanks everyone for helping me look for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was trying to send information across the phones outside the I/O stream. I send the string "start timer" and look for it in the handler. Works perfectly! Thanks everyone for helping me look for the answer.